# How to split Ava tests Into multiple files?

Tags: node.js, testing, ava

According to [Ava's documentation](https://github.com/avajs/ava), I should create a file named `test.js` at the root of my project. But having a single file for my tests seems like a recipe for maintenance nightmares. Thus, I want to split my tests into multiple files, all within a folder named `tests` and somehow run them from my `test.js` file.

For example, let's say we have a test file named `./tests/basic-tests.js` with this code:

```js
    import test from ava;
    import {Calculator} from calculator;

    test('it calculates',t =>{
      //Some test here
    });
```

And an another file named `./tests/burn_it_down.js`:

```js
    import test from ava;
    import {SethRollins} from wwe;

    test('Burned it Down',t =>{
      //Another tests here
    });
```

I want `test.js` to somehow run both the tests in `./tests/basic-tests.js` and in `./tests/burn_it_down.js`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVA works with multiple files, too. `tests/` isn't in the default search pattern though (`test/` is). Assuming you're configuring AVA through the `package.json` file you can do:

```
{
  "ava": {
    "files": "./tests/*.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an error saying `The 'files' configuration must be an array containing glob patterns`. So I changed it to: `"files": ["./tests/*.js"]`